# $q.reject and handling errors in AngularJS chained promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, chaining

I'm having trouble understanding a basic concept of error handling with chaining promises.
In order to learn the rules, I have written a simple example, guessing what the result will be. But unfortunatly it doesn't behave as I though it will.
I have read multiple articles about the subject but perhaps can't I get details because of my poor english language.

Anyway, here is my code :

```
    var promiseStart = $q.when("start");
    var promise1 = promiseStart.then(function() {
            return Serviceforpromise1.get();
    });
    var promise2 = promise1.then(function(data1)
    {
            return Serviceforpromise2.get(data1);
    },function(error)
    {
            return $q.reject();
    });
    var promiseend = promise2.then(function(data2)
    {
            return data2;
    },function(error)
    {
            return error;
    });
    return promiseend;
```

Well I know that it can be way better coded but it's just for the purpose.
Here is the code of Serviceforpromise1 function :

```
    function Serviceforpromise1()
    {
            ...
            return $http.get(*whatever*).then(function (data){
                return data;
            },function(error)
            {
                return $q.reject();
            });
    }
```

Consider only the case of Serviceforpromise1's failure.  A **$q.rejec**t is sent back to main chain so I'm waiting the error callback of "**promise1 .then(**" to be called and it worked as expected. I decided for the example  to transfert the error to the "**promise2 .then**" so in this error callback I added the line **return $q.reject()**;
But it never reached the second error callback (the "**promise2 .then**" one) and I don't understand why (like Serviceforpromise1, I returned a rejected promise !)

I will be happy to deeply understand what is happening here.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How have you checked that `promise2`'s error callback isn't being called? I don't see anything there that would tell you if it was called.

Comment: Yes I log into console but remove the logging code for the post to not bother with unrelevant lines

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, and the problem appears to lie somewhere in the way you are trying to observe this behavior (in something you haven't shown us).

If you return a rejected promise from *either* a success or error handler in `then()`, then the promise returned by `then()` will resolve to a rejected promise. Observe:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('C', [
    '$q',

function ($q) {
    var promiseStart = $q.when("start");
    var promise1 = promiseStart.then(function (value) {
        console.log('Got a value:', value);
        return $q.reject('Error!');
    });

    var promise2 = promise1.then(function (data1) {
        return "Got some stuff";
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Caught an error:", error);
        return $q.reject('New error');
    });

    var promiseend = promise2.then(function (data2) {
        return data2;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Caught an error:', error);  // <-- this is logged to the console
        return error;
    });

    return promiseend;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='C'></div>
```

One thing to note here is that in that last handler, you are *returning* the `error` variable, and not throwing an exception or returning a rejected promise. So in this case, `promiseend` will *successfully* resolve with the value of that `error` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm reassured on one side but anxious on the other. You example is working perfectly fine. I will try to cut and paste your code and replace each line by mine to find my mistake. I will came back with comments. thanks

Comment: **Update** : ok you were right JLRishe. It was a typo that I fixed when I wrote my example on stackoverflow leaving leaving the bug on my original code. Thanks for pointing it to me and thanks for confirming my gess.

Comment: @JLRishe Is there a reason you return the error data as successful? From what I understand rejected promises don't halt execution of the JavaScript. I'm just wondering because I'm still getting a hang of promises and it seems you could do it either way.

Comment: @Usagi I'm returning an error there because that's what OP did in their code. All I did to that portion was add a `console.log` to show what was going on. I agree that one typically wouldn't return an error from an error handler; they would either rethrow, throw a new error, return some value, or return nothing.